# how can i attach an icon near H1 tag?

Tags: css, html

I have few menus with titles, and next to them attached icons, the following code is working correctly:

```
<div class="contentcont">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a class="navbar" href="index.htm">
            <img src="navhome.png" alt="Home" height="12" width="14"></a>
            <a class="navbar" href="index.htm">Login</a>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
```

when trying to add the same icon next to a different class it is showing the icon above (if written above) or under (if written under) but no on the same line, i have tried to change:

```
    <div class="infoboxheader infoboxheaderuser">
        <img src="navhome.png" alt="Home" height="12" width="14"></a>
        <h1 class="infobox">Login to Real Estate</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="infoboxbody">
```

css info of infobox:

```
h1.infobox{
      color: #5d5d5d;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bolder;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

notice that's a different class, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: where is your css? create a jsfiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: here is the css of class infobox h1.infobox{color: #5d5d5d;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bolder;padding-left: 10px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;text-transform: uppercase;}

Comment: Instead adding to comment edit your question with CSS. please paste the CSS of other related elements too. Try using as background image for `h1` or

Comment: already done this in both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using styles for `img` tag. like,

```
.infoboxheader img{float:left;margin-top:2px}
```

here is a working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/t8tokcth/1/